# Redirigir subdominios a local host con el fichero Host de windows

Tags: windows

Estoy intentando redirigir `N` cantidad de `subdominios`  a local host `127.0.0.1` con el  fichero `host` de windows.

He intentado utilizar el comodin  `*`

```
127.0.0.1  *.dominio.com
```

Al parecer esto no funciona correctamente o no es compatible con expresiones regulares.

¿Alguna idea ?

Comment: El fichero `hosts`no soporta los llamados `wildcards`. Una opción, si no quieres escribir a mano los `N`subdominios, es configurar tu propia máquina para actuar de Proxy. Podrías usar [Acrylic DNS Proxy](https://mayakron.altervista.org/support/acrylic/Home.htm), que es OpenSource para realizar esta configuración. Dicho Proxy DNS si que acepta `wildcards` en su fichero de `hosts`. Saludos

Comment: Esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-windows-hosts-file#9695861) del sitio en inglés explica cómo configurar Acrylic DNS Proxy. Saludos